# AJAX requests and THIS

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having a little problem when trying to target an `A tag` inside a $('div').fadeOut() callback.

I got this

```
$('.anchor').click(function() {
    $('#div').fadeOut(null, showDiv);
    $('#div').fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

**showDiv** is an AJAX request which I use `$(this)` inside it trying to refer to the `A tag` clicked but I noticed that it refers to the `div #div`

**What I want to do** is to do some AJAX request when a `link`is clicked, but I want it to happen only after the DIV's fade out. This way, the request would populate `#div` and the new content will only show up when it fades in again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the context using [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), like this:

```
$('.anchor').click(function() {
  $('#div').fadeOut(null, $.proxy(showDiv, this));
  $('#div').fadeIn();
  return false;
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/sfa5v/), or do the same thing manually:

```
$('.anchor').click(function() {
  var self = this;
  $('#div').fadeOut(null, function() {
    showDiv.apply(self);
  });
  $('#div').fadeIn();
  return false;
});
```